# Is it possible to get the URL of an already signed document via embed signing in DocuSign?

Tags: docusignapi

For example, a user successfully signed a document. And I want the document to be viewed via the browser by getting its URL. I know there is a email notification about the document completion and a link to review the document. But is there a way to get that certain type of URL from the DocuSign API?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if the document is completed/signed and you make the same API call previously to start the embedded signing experience, you will receive a URL to view the documents in read only mode in the DocuSign experience in the browser.

Comment: meaning I have to make the url via the RecipientViewRequest again? to get the read only mode of the url, and the same clientUserID, recepient info must be the same is that what you were saying?

Comment: Okay I tried it,but it only works for a few seconds or swaped browsers. I was looking for a perma url just like the url of the signed document via the email. Is it possible?

Comment: Ok understood now - you cannot use the DS API to generate a permanent URL for this case. You can generate your own URL which will then need to generate the short lived URL (via DocuSign), and re-direct the user to DS.